# Always open wxPython GUI with scroll bar selected

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

I have several GUIs which open progressively that are all experiencing the same issue.  When I open them, the first object which is selected is a `TextCtrl` object.  These GUIs are rather large and have scroll bars.  Since a `TextCtrl` object is selected, scrolling with the mouse wheel does nothing and makes it appear as if the scroll bars are broken.  To demonstrate this, I made the following code:

```
import wx

class Tester(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Window", size=(500, 500))
        self.panel = wx.ScrolledWindow(self,wx.ID_ANY) 
        self.panel.SetScrollbars(30,30,600,400)

        textBox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", size=(200, 150), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_LEFT)
        textStuff = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "A\nbunch\nof\nlines\nto\nmake\nthis\nlong\nenough\nto\nhave\nscroll\nbars\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nIts lonely down here\n\n\n\n:(")
        lonelyBtn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "So Lonely")


        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(textBox, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)
        vbox.Add(textStuff, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)
        vbox.Add(lonelyBtn, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)

        panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        panel.Layout()

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
Tester().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

When you run this and try to scroll down, you'll notice you cannot scroll with the mouse wheel.

So far, this all makes sense. Here's where it gets a little weird.  If the selected object is a `Button`, using the mouse wheel engages the scroll bars. You can test this by pressing the button, then using the mouse wheel.  Also, **clicking on the panel, or even the scroll bar itself, doesn't allow the mouse wheel to work.**

**What I'm looking for** is a way to make sure that if there are scroll bars, they can be used with the mouse wheel upon displaying the GUI (they are selected by default). I can accept that the mouse wheel will not function once a user clicks into the text control.

Additionally, if you have an explanation for why the mouse wheel works for buttons and not text controls, I'd love to hear it

**EDIT:** I know I can add a listener (thanks to Mr. Joran Beasley), but this means that the scroll bars within a multi-line text control can never be used with the mouse wheel.  The ideal solution (which I'm not sure is possible), is to have clicking on anywhere outside the text control (panel or scroll bar) allows the mouse wheel to scroll the panel.  Is this possible?

Additionally, I've switched over to using `ScrolledWindow` instead of `ScrolledPanel`

**EDIT 2:** The fix was to use the following:

```
self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.onMouseMove)

def onMouseMove(self, event):
        self.panel.SetFocusIgnoringChildren()
```

---

**EDIT 3:** The *actual* fix was to do something a little tricky.  Using the code below I bound only multiline text controls to `EVT_ENTER_WINDOW` and `EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW` as well as binding every item (and the panel itself) to `EVT_MOUSEWHEEL`.  Then a logical `self.inMLTxtCtrl` tracks if the mouse if over any of the multiline text controls

```
self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.onWheel)
for sizerItem in self.panel.GetSizer().GetChildren():
    try:
        if sizerItem.GetWindow().IsMultiLine():
            sizerItem.GetWindow().Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.onMouseEnter)
            sizerItem.GetWindow().Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.onMouseLeave)
            sizerItem.GetWindow().Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.onWheel)
    except:
        sizerItem.GetWindow().Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL, self.onWheel)
```

Then a logical `self.inMLTxtCtrl` tracks if the mouse if over any of the multiline text controls as shown below.

```
def onMouseEnter(self, event):
    print "entering"
    self.inMLTxtCtrl = True

def onMouseLeave(self, event):
    print "leaving"
    self.inMLTxtCtrl = False
```

Finally, the `onWheel()` function uses this logical flag to determine where to scroll.  If the mouse is in a multiline text control when the scroll wheel is turned, it attempts to scroll in that text control.  Othewise, the `SetFocusIgnoringChildren()` function is called and the panel is scrolled.  Since the panel and text control use different scrolling methods, a `try...except` is needed.

```
def onWheel(self, event):
    if self.inMLTxtCtrl:
        print "in", event.GetWheelRotation()
    else:
        print "out", event.GetWheelRotation()
        self.panel.SetFocusIgnoringChildren()

    try:
        currScroll = self.panel.FindFocus().GetViewStart()
        newScroll = (currScroll[0],currScroll[1]- event.GetWheelRotation()/60)
        self.panel.FindFocus().Scroll(*newScroll)
    except:
        self.panel.FindFocus().ScrollLines(event.GetWheelRotation()/-60)
```

Comment: ... you can certainly add listeners for wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL to text fields to redirect the scroll to the scrollbars

Comment: That sounds ideal, how would I do that?

Comment: updated my answer to make it more in line with what you want .... still not exactly what you asked for but meh :/ (its based on the ScrolledPanel version still , although Im sure you can tweak it easy enough to the ScrolledWindow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Tester(wx.Frame):
    def OnTxtScroll(self,e):
        currScroll = self.panel.GetViewStart()
        newScroll = (currScroll[0],currScroll[1]- e.GetWheelRotation()/120)
        self.panel.Scroll(*newScroll)

    def __init__(self):
        ....
        #your code
        ....
        self.panel = panel
        textBox.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSEWHEEL,self.OnTxtScroll)
```

after your clarification ... I think that this would work (its a bit hacky and doesnt do exactly what you describe ... but it might work)

```
 def OnTxtScroll(self,e):
        print dir(e)
        target = e.GetEventObject()
        p1 = target.GetScrollPos(wx.VERTICAL)
        e.Skip()
        self.Update()
        def updateScroll(p1,target,scroll_amt):
            p2 = target.GetScrollPos(wx.VERTICAL)
            if p1 ==p2:#scroll did not effect target object so lets scroll our main panel
                currScroll = self.panel.GetViewStart()
                newScroll = (currScroll[0],currScroll[1]- scroll_amt)
                self.panel.Scroll(*newScroll)
        wx.CallAfter(updateScroll,p1,target,e.GetWheelRotation()/120)
```

Comment: This works with one slight hitch, the mouse wheel now always scrolls the panel, never the text control, which makes sense, but its not a trade off I'd like to make.  +1 because it works, but I don't want to accept it. I'll clarify the question to make what I'm looking for more clear

Comment: I revised my question again with a better fix in case you're curious.  Thanks again, I would not have figured this out without your answer!